# pygame.error: video system not initialized pygame.init() already called

Tags: python, pygame

Why this error is coming I am not understanding  can anyone please tell why is it coming and how to correct it?
[image]

Comment: show your code as text

Answer (score 0):

For every event in the event queue, you call [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit), which will deinitialize all pygame modules:

> `pygame.quit()`
>
> *uninitialize all pygame modules*
>
> `quit() -> None`
>
> Uninitialize all pygame modules that have previously been initialized. When the Python interpreter shuts down, this method is called regardless, so your program should not need it, except when it wants to terminate its pygame resources and continue. It is safe to call this function more than once as repeated calls have no effect.
>
> **Note**
>    Calling `pygame.quit()`uninitialize all pygame modules will not exit your program. Consider letting your program end in the same way a normal Python program will end.

So in the next iteration of the `while` loop, the call to `pygame.event.get()` will fail because the video system is no longer initialzed.

You should check the `type` attribute of the `event` object against the `pygame.QUIT` constant, and not call the `pygame.quit()` function:

```
...
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    ...
```

Usually there's no need to ever call `pygame.quit()`.